# Performance difference between returning a value directly or creating a temporary variable

Tags: c#, performance, memory

Is there any performance hit or memory consumption difference to creating a temporary variable in a function compared to returning directly the value assigned to this variable?

For example, which of these functions (GetValue) are better in performance and for saving memory or both are exactly the same:

Case 1:

```
  private string GetValue()
  {
     return this.GetResult();
  }

  private string GetResult()
  {
     // Code here that return a big string...
  }
```

Case 2:

```
  private string GetValue()
  {
     string result = this.GetResult();

     return result;
  }

  private string GetResult()
  {
     // Code here that return a big string...
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Most likely after optimization the code will be identical

Comment: This is the sort of thing to leave to the compiler to optimize away. In general, feel free to make local variables without fear if it makes the code more readable. The compiler will optimize away any perceived inefficiencies you might think they would cause.

Comment: If the JIT doesn't optimize it away, the performance difference will be so small that I don't think it's even worth thinking about.

Comment: As others have mentioned, compiler optimization would likely remove any difference between these two approaches. Regardless, though, I'm very confident that you will never have any performance problems that can be solved by changing from one of these approaches to the other.

Comment: I've found that liberal use of local variables makes the variable watch window in a debugger much more useful.  For me, this trumps any efficiency differences.

Comment: Wow, thank you all... a lot of answers is so minimal time since I posted. I will surely vote up to the maintainability and readability of my code like @Adam said. I will let the question open a couple of hours just to see what others have to say about the subjet.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar - I can confirm that when compiled with `optimize+` (release mode) that the IL code generated is identical for both.

Comment: Related https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141711/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In these basic situations, readability **always** trumps performance differences. I'd consider this a micro-optimisation at best, and these largely turn out to be wastes of time. What you save on this will be eaten up by an undeterministic GC run.

Most of the time there are no differences in the resulting code if the compiler is allowed to optimise it. The resulting IL in this case seems to have a few extra op codes for a reference to the string on the stack, but what the JIT then does with this is anyone's guess.

I sometimes break out into temporary variables to review them before returning, but I never worry about the performance impact.  Most importantly, I have never seen a case where this sort of improvement was required to solve a performance problem.

Comment: Just to add, the extra op codes as reported by LINQPad are just an extra `ldloc` then `stloc`.  This would only be in a debug build I would assume anyway.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair No this was a release build targeting x86 with optimisations turned on.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair No idea, I was using ILSpy. Definitely in release mode though, the IL for it is less verbose than that of my debug version. I can post it if you like?

Comment: Naw, that's alright.  I know it's generally a good thing to know the equivalent IL and how the compiler works to put it together, but sometimes it's just what it is! Probably some reason behind it.  If you think it'll help your answer or Samuel, go ahead.  Can't be much different than what LINQPad reported anyway; the C# code is very simple.

Answer (score 5):

If the local variable is actually used by the executable code, and not optmised away, then the difference is still minimal.

The local variable uses just the stack space needed to store the reference, and allocating the space for it takes no time at all as the stack frame is always allocated anyway.

The time to make the extra copy to and from the local variable would hardly be possible to measure. It would only make a difference if you would call the method millions of times in a tight loop, and it would still only be a tiny fraction of the execution time compared to the time it takes to allocate a string.

Answer (score 2):

The local variable is always optimised.

**There is no performance impact of using a local variable before a return statement since the Compiler optimizes the code.**

So, after the compilation, the Case 2 code will look exactly like Case 1.

```
  private string GetValue()
  {
     // string result = this.GetResult(); // this is optimized to the below line by compiler

     return this.GetResult();
  }

  private string GetResult()
  {
     // Code here that return a big string...
  }
```

[See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEDMACFAmDB1ASxgAsB7AVxgDUIECJgAbODAWACgBvDjXrARgAMGeLAAUASh59u7PhgCQKAOwYARADs4AdwDKMOhoDmagNzTeAXw7X2HDuiy5CJGnQbM2XCwOGiYkj6y8goAbrQYYACe+oZGGAC86lp6BgTGZj7yKpExacbmcny2lkA===) for the actual output generated by the Compiler when we use a variable and when we don't before returning a result.

I prefer using the local variable always as it speeds up debugging.
According to [this](https://coralogix.com/log-analytics-blog/this-is-what-your-developers-are-doing-75-of-the-time-and-this-is-the-cost-you-pay/), developers spend 75% of their time debugging.

**UPDATE**:
As pointed out by @surfmuggle in the comments, there could be a slight impact (two additional lines of IL code) of using a local variable. But, as said in the accepted answer, readability takes preference over such nano-optimizations.

Comment: If two methods return a string and one uses a local variable then the ILCode is different - at least according to [this sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgZgATIEzoOpmAAsB7AV2ADUBDAJzCoCMIBTdAWACgBvT9PzAIwAGdMGYBnYAIAUASl78eHfugCQyAOzoARADtmAdwDKwOroDm2gNwK+AX1uCRYyVjmOlK1QDda6ALYAniZm5ugAvDr6xqZgFtaOKpoBwbEWNsr8Dhx2QA=)