# What is the difference in these ways of assigning a variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is the difference between creating a variable specifically to assign a variable vs using the new keyword to create one in line with the assignment of value? I understand that they both end up with the same result, I would just like to know if there is any performance differences and stuff like that.

For example:

```
this.transform.position = new Vector3(mousePosInBlocks, this.gameObject.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
```

vs

```
Vector3 temp = new Vector3(mousePosInBlocks, this.gameObject.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
this.gameObject.transform.position = temp;
```

This example code uses Unity 5s position system with game objects..

Comment: Can you compare the compiled code? I'd expect they'll be exactly the same code in release mode.

Comment: @Rup I just looked at the compiled code and it appears to be the same, just the lines are in a little bit different order. Thanks!

Comment: @Rup I'm a bit new to StackOverflow, so I'm not sure if this is the only way, but if you create a short answer, I'll mark it as correct and upvote it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can answer yourself just fine... Also you could have found answer before posting the question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798033/performance-difference-between-returning-a-value-directly-or-creating-a-temporar/11798105

Comment: @Rup Sorry, I tried looking for my answer before posting, but I could not find it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The first one requires more horizontal space. The second one requires more vertical space.

Comment: @JlRishe Hahaha, thanks!

Comment: No problem! (and that wasn't me!) Besides, it's much easier to spot that two questions are the same when you already know the answer, so it's never a problem in my book.

Comment: In the "vertical" example, you are able to debug the variable temp a bit easier than stepping into the "horizontal" code. YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two have the same end result, however the second method is unnecessary as the new variable 'temp' is created and stored in memory. So it takes up a little memory and a small amount of processing power to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

The compiled code was essentially the same, meaning little to no differences. Thanks to @Rup for pointing this out for me.